# Admob ads not displayed

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play, admob

I have a game on Google Play it was showing ads (Banner ads) now there is no ads are displayed

What are the possible causes ?

In build.gradle I have this:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0
```

the latest version is 9.4.0 could this be a possible cause ? But in this way if it is a cause I should update my app for each update of google-play-services

Another thing: I put ads in play screen so player see ads most of the time Is this a problem as I read something about accidental clicks within Admob policies

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mygdx.clockspuzzle"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Clocks Puzzles"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mygdx.clockspuzzle.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="Clocks Puzzles"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

`AndroidLauncher` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // gameView
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(this), config);

    // adView
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adView.loadAd(builder.build());


    // add gameView
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // add adView
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

the point that I am talking about is ads were displayed correctly without a problem.

Comment: add you xml file and admob code written , also share logs

Comment: I edit question

Comment: please upload logs as well. filter them with Ads

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Comment: I found this message when I used my device as test device "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 598x32 dp, but only has 360x592

Comment: in your relativelayout add android:paddingLeft="0dp"
 android:paddingRight="0dp"

Comment: also change adParams android:layout_width="match_parent"